# How to make a batch file that copies itself to all available network locations?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch which can copy itself to all available network locations.
I know how to make a batch file that can copy itself to a network location whose name is known. I want to make a batch file which copies itself to all network locations without specifying the name of the location.
Is there any command like %server% which can help me.
I am actually new to bat programming.
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You have to give more details on what is your goal. Share what you already have please.

Comment: NET VIEW may give what you want - but it is using the master browser so is limited to Windows computers  eg FOR /F %v IN ('net view') DO echo %v

Comment: As another way, you could look to enumerate all IP addresses on a subnet and address computers that way before either calling `net view \\ip` to discover shares or make the assumption you can write to standard admin shares, e.g. C$ to save the enumeration of the shares available.